# Error while updating a project in Maven

Tags: maven

I am getting this below exception when I am trying to update a project in Maven.

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
>   `org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.WTPProjectsUtil.isM2eWtpDisabled(Lorg/eclipse/m2e/core/project/IMavenProjectFacade;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Z`

Comment: I suggest you get the latest Eclipse and M2Eclipse version. This will probably solve this.

Comment: Can you post your entire stack please ?